# How to read Eigen factor and AI for a journal in specific field?

Tags: research-process, journals, bibliometrics

I am trying to understand the reputation of a journal in specific field of science. I am looking at this journal [CHI Paper](http://www.eigenfactor.org/rankings.php?bsearch=ACM%20Transactions%20on%20Computer-Human%20Interaction&searchby=journal&orderby=eigenfactor). How do I read the information from the graphs and figure out how this journal compares to other journals?

Comment: Did you try reading their faq and comparing the numbers to those of other journals? On the other hand, I've never heard of a journal's eigen factor before.

Comment: Both eigenfactors and *Article influence score* (AI) are reported by Thomson ISI, so its well known. Look at the FAQ at http://www.eigenfactor.org/ and at the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenfactor. In general, AI is more comparable to IF, while eigenfactor scales with the number of papers published. Also have a look at SNIP and SJR if you are interested in journal metrics (http://www.journalmetrics.com/values.php).

Comment: If you want to understand the *reputation* of a journal, you should discuss this journal with experts in the field, rather than looking at citation statistics.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [entire list of journals in the field **Information theory**](http://www.eigenfactor.org/rankings.php?search=129&year=2011&searchby=efcat&orderby=ArticleInfluence), where this journals belongs. There you see that *ACM Transactions on Computer-Human Interaction* is at place 53 out of 248, ranked by AI. By combining this number with knowledge of the field you can probably draw some conclusions.

In general, both *eigenfactors* and the *Article influence score* (AI) are reported by Thomson ISI as well, so they are well known. Look at the [FAQ](http://www.eigenfactor.org/faq.php) at eigenfactor.org and read the wikipedia article on [eigenfactor](http://www.en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenfactor) for more info. In general, AI is more comparable to the impact factor, while the eigenfactor scales with the number of papers published in the journal. Also have a look at SNIP and SJR if you are interested in journal metrics, info can be found at [journalmetrics.com](http://www.journalmetrics.com/values.php).